# Azure Databricks Secret Scope: Azure Key Vault-backed or Databricks-backed

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a way to determine if an already existing Azure Databricks Secret Scope is backed by Key Vault or Databricks via a python notebook? `dbutils.secrets.listScopes()` does not output this. Assume that I have Manage permissions on the scope.
(Unfortunately, Google didn't help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either via Secrets REST API - if you use [List Secret Scopes API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets#--list-secret-scopes), then `backend_type` field shows the backend - Datbricks or KeyVault.  From notebook you can do it with following code:

```py
import requests
ctx = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext()
host_name = ctx.tags().get("browserHostName").get()
host_token = "your_PAT_token"
cluster_id = ctx.tags().get("clusterId").get()

response = requests.get(
    f'https://{host_name}/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/list',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'}
  ).json()
scopes = dict([(s['name'], s.get('backend_type', 'DATABRICKS')) 
               for s in response['scopes']])
backend = scopes['scope-name']
```

Or you can do the same via databricks-cli, using the `databricks secrets list-scopes` command (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/secrets-cli))

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm accessing via a Databricks python notebook and `dbutils.secrets.listScopes()` doesn't output the backend (Updated the question)

Comment: I've added code example for fetching list of scopes via API

Comment: using cli command  `databricks secrets list-scope --profile mycluster`, helped me in listing the key-vault that was used in workspace.